# Maximal ideal $M$ is prime in commutative (non unital) ring A such that $A^2\neq0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Is this proof correct?

$M$ is maximal $\iff A/M$ has no proper non trivial ideal

$M$ is prime ideal $\iff A/M$ is a domain

Now, suppose $A/M$ is a commutative ring with no proper non trivial ideal and $\left( A/M \right)^2\neq0$. For every $x\in A/M$, the set $\{y \in A/M |yx=0\}$ is an ideal. Now, let $x$ be a zero divisor. Because $M$ is maximal, $\{y \in A/M |yx=0\}=A/M$. But then, every element is a zero divisor. But then $xy=0 \forall x,y \in A/M$, contradiction

Comment: Did you notice $(A/M)^2$ is an ideal? So that $(A/M)^2=A/M$?  Maybe a better way to look at it is that if $x\notin M$, $(x+M)=A/M$.

Comment: Actually, can you clarify what you are asking? Your title says one thing, then you mention a proof followed by two biconditionals, and the question title looks like a question about the paragraph that follows.  Are you trying to prove the first biconditoinal?  If so, probably omit the second for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning that every element of $A/M$ must be a zero divisor is not correct; taking $x=0$ (note that $0$ is always a zero divisor) in any ring $R$ will yield $\{y\in R\,|\,xy = 0\} = R$.